# CakePHP2.X : How to write edit method while using RESTful web service

Tags: web-services, cakephp, rest

I am using cakephp2.2 version and I followed the documentation available at url http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html

Now in the edit method, what will be the `edit.ctp` which contains edit form to place at `views/receip/xml/.`

When i put the edit form in the `Views/Receip/xml/` folder, that generates xml kind of form:

Everyone writes for the index method code but nobody writes for the edit method code. Can somebody guide how to write edit method so if I send `recipes/edit/1.xml` I get html form filled with data?

Answer (score 1):

The XML view should look pretty close to the index view in the example, with the exception of the variable that it's spitting out.

I'm assuming you're using the same edit function as in the example:

```
public function edit($id) {
    $this->Recipe->id = $id;
    if ($this->Recipe->save($this->request->data)) {
        $message = 'Saved';
    } else {
        $message = 'Error';
    }
    $this->set(array(
        'message' => $message,
        '_serialize' => array('message')
    ));
}
```

As stated in the book:

> You can also easily make JSON views using CakePHP’s built in JSON and
>   XML views. By using the built in XmlView we can define a _serialize
>   view variable. This special view variable is used to define which view
>   variables XmlView should serialize into XML.

If you're not using the builtin view, however, you can manually dictate the XML in your view like so (make sure to take the `_serialize` view var out of the `edit` function so it doesn't automatically generate your XML).

The view should look like this:

```
$xml = Xml::fromArray(array('message' => $message));
echo $xml->asXML();
```

This will output a very basic XML document with the success message as a node. You can feel free to add more information. For example, if the update fails, you should tell your users what didn't validate by including the validation errors in the XML response.

Comment: Yes. my question is "if I send recipes/edit/1.xml I get html form filled with data?" I dont want json or xml view. I want data with simeple html form to edit.

Comment: Oh, just change the view then :) You wouldn't want the `.xml` extension either if you're not delivering HTML. The idea behind the edit view here is that they would POST vars to it and the edit view is the response, not the form. To make it a form you'd have to edit your routes. Can you post your routes in the original post? After that I can help.